# Create growing steps line in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm designing Logo in Photoshop, trying to create increasing steps from single line which show's growth. it look like same as **stair steps** and i used pencil tool but created object not looking so nice.

Please help.....

Comment: This question is extremely off-topic. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for the kind of questions you should ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*These steps are for Illustrator*
You might try the blend tool. Create your start and end objects, in shape, size and position. Select both shapes and go to Object>Blend>Make. By default it will likely make too many or too few steps. Remedy this by going to Object>Blend>Blend Options and change it from Smooth Color to Specified Steps. Here you can specify how many steps to create. Once you are happy with the results, go to Object>Expand and it will make it into editable objects. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple. Select Pen tool and simply click until you are happy with your shape. You can move your anchor points by holding ctrl + mouse click. I think you dont need curves for steps. When you will be satisfied with that either right click and select stroke or make a selection. :)